# Setting global variables with Cactus App for Mac

Tags: python, html, django, macos, templates

For those of you who aren't familiar, [Cactus](http://cactusformac.com) is a static site generator app for Mac. It compiles your files and lets you write templating code in Django.

Their docs show you how to do [custom variables](http://cactusformac.com/docs/extras.html#variables), which is great. **But I'm stumped on how to achieve global variables that apply to all templates.**

I've attempted to Google this, but all the Django/python-centric answers are for a pure python setup and don't really apply to this specific app. I've also tried contacting the authors, but no response.

This question is for anyone that may have worked with Cactus before. *fingers crossed*

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Cactus has a 'config' tag that lets you access variables specified in the config.json file.

So if your config.json contains the following line:

"email": "webmaster@example.com",

...then in your templates, you can reference this with:

{% config "email" %}

Hope this answer was worth the 18 month wait!

Answer (score 0):

@Anton answer works fine for printing global variables, but... for using them on blocks is better to put them on context entry in config.json. This way you can access them on the templates way easier.

If you want to do:

```
<meta name="author" content="{{ blog.author }}">
```

Declare in config.json:

```
{
  ...
  "context": {
    "blog": {
      "id": "fancy-site",
      "author": "Joe Blogs",
      "description": "Such a fancy site"
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/eudicots/Cactus/issues/125

You can use this for arrays too. It's JSON. I use it for declaring nested menus, for instance, iterating with for loop block.